# 4*4 Word Square #2

Tags: crosswords, word-square

A word square is a puzzle in which letters can be placed into the grid below so that words are formed both horizontally and vertically. In this puzzle, the same four words are formed in each direction.

[image: the 4*4 grid]

The clues, in no particular order, are as follows:

- Orderly
- Amish Pride
- Shortened name of virus
- Sunburn Treatment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I've got this one:

> BARN
> ALOE
> RONA
> NEAT

Comment: congratulations! : )